# I am unable to get the ID in the url string

Tags: php, jquery

I am passing the ID in onclick function,but when I get the id in the page ,it says "undefined index ID".

Here is the php code which passes the ID to the url

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="ok">
            <img style='width: 200px' src="images/<?php echo $pics; ?>" alt="name" onclick="location.href='#img?ID=<?php echo $imgid ?>' ;img('<?php echo $pics ?>','<?php echo $imgid ?>')"  > 
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is onclick results in url

```
http://localhost/2/2/mvc/view/main.php#img?ID=50
```

Here is how I am calling the URL ID

```
<?php  $gid=$_GET['ID']; echo $gid;  ?>
```

and here is the error shown

> Notice: Undefined index: ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\2\2\mvc\view\main.php on line 126

Comment: Im pretty sure the issue must be the hash

Comment: fragments dont get send to the server

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fragment+url+php

Answer (score 4):

The URL should be:

```
http://localhost/2/2/mvc/view/main.php?ID=50#img
```

i.e. The `hash` part should come *after* all the `GET` parameters

Comment: THanks for ur quick response,it wors but i am using fancybox which opens only  when the #img is given in the url after main.php.but after ur suggestion,i removed #img,now fancybox opens but again disappers,however it gives the url ID

Answer (score 2):

here is the error `echo $imgid` should be `echo $imgid;`

it should be like

```
onclick="location.href='?ID=<?php   echo $imgid ;?>'#img
```

also the `#img` which show the image should be at the end of the url

Comment: THanks for ur quick response,it wors but i am using fancybox which opens only when the #img is given in the url after main.php.but after ur suggestion,i removed #img,now fancybox opens but again disappers,however it gives the url ID